# Find $a$ if $h(2018)=a^3$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Suppose
>
> $$\begin{cases}f(x)=g(x+1)\\f(y)=2018y+2016y+\cdots+2y\\g(x)=h(2x)-x\end{cases}$$
>
> If $h(2018)=a^3$ and $a\in\mathbb Z$, what is the value of $a$?

The answer is $1009$. I found it by solving for $h(2x)$ in terms of $f(x)$,

$$h(2018)=f(1008)+1009$$

then applying Faulhaber's formula to $f(y)$,

$$f(y)=y\sum_{i=0}^{1008}(2018-2i)=1\,019\,090y$$

$a^3=1\,027\,243\,729$ happens to be a perfect cube, and $a=1009$.

But given the relationship between the solution $1009$ and $2018$, I suspect there may be a more elegant way to find $a$. Is there one?

Disclaimer: I'm assuming this comes from a $2018$ contest purely because the number appears in the question.

Comment: Generalizing $2018$ by $2n$ we can solve the problem the same way: $f(x) = n(n+1)x$, $g(x) = n(n+1)(x-1)$ and $h(2x) = n(n+1)(x-1) + x$. Then $h(2n) = n(n+1)(n-1) + n = n^3$. So it just happens that no matter which $n$ you choose, $h(2n)$ will be a perfect cube and its cube root is equal to $n$ itself. Looks like it's just a consequence of this algebraic identity.

Comment: (I should clarify that $h(x)$ is not necessarily a perfect cube for all $x$, but that the function $h_n$ corresponding to the choice of $n$ will be a perfect cube for $x = 2n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \begin{split} h(2018) &= h(2\cdot 1009) \\
&= g(1009)+1009 = \\ 
&= g(1008 + 1)+1009 = \\ 
&= f(1008)+1009 = \\ 
&= \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{1009}2\cdot i \cdot 1008\right)+1009 = \\ 
&= 2\cdot 1008\cdot\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{1009} i\right)+1009 = \\ 
&= 2\cdot 1008\cdot\left(\frac{1009\cdot 1010}{2}\right)+1009 = \\ 
&= 1008\cdot 1009\cdot 1010+1009 = \\ 
&= 1009\cdot (1008\cdot 1010+1) = \\ 
&= 1009\cdot \left((1009-1)\cdot (1009+1)+1\right) = \\ 
&= 1009\cdot (1009^2 - 1 +1) = \\ 
&= 1009^3.
\end{split}$$

Hence $a = 1009$.